# Solve for the coordinates of the center of each circle in this fractal-like image

Tags: geometry

Finding the center of the yellow and black circles is very easy. Finding the center of the green circles is medium easy. Finding the center of the red and blue circles is rather challenging.

[image]

Comment: Hint: if you can find the green ones, rotate and reflect to find the blue and red ones.

Comment: Yes, I performed a reflection to find the red ones. However, that took me about an hour to solve!

Comment: I don't see how there should be any difference in difficulty between red, green, blue?!

Comment: The gray, green, and yellow circles share a horizontal common external tangent. So solving for the center of the green circles only requires Pythagorean Theorem. The gray, red, and yellow circles share a common external tangent with a slope of +/-sqrt(3). Using transformations to solve was very time consuming. Please let me know if you have a more elegant method.

Comment: Do you know how to rotate a point about the center by means of a 2X2 matrix multiplication?  You calculate one and rotate one by $120^0$ (or other angles if you just want to make it "easier").

Comment: Yes, thank you. Your suggested method is indeed much "easier" but requires trigonometry.